# IE8 seems to be skipping lines of javascript code?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Here's the url: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1261672/groovyBox%20-%20Copy/groovyBox.html

This works in Chrome by the way.

And then it gets down to line 186 and it looks like it just completely ignores that entire block, as evidenced by the fact that the alert doesn't happen.

Any ideas?

```
getPlaylist(function(songs) {
        alert("test");
            // if (shuffle==1){songs=songs.sort( randOrd );}
            // playlistFromXML = songs;
            // playlistFromXML = JSON.parse(songs);
            // alert(playlistFromXML);
var mediaPlaylist = new Playlist("1", songs, {
    ready: function() {
        mediaPlaylist.displayPlaylist();
        mediaPlaylist.playlistInit(false); // Parameter is a boolean for autoplay.
    },
    ended: function() {
        mediaPlaylist.playlistNext();
    },
    swfPath: "js",
    supplied: "ogv, m4v, oga, mp3"
}); 
         });
```

Edit: hmm you are right, okay got the alert working...but on the page, it doesn't load any songs in the jplayer like it does in chrome. maybe this isn't where the problem lies...

THANKS for all your help everyone. I think I better take this to the jplayer forums.

for those who care, it ended up being a problem with my jplayer code. I had the wrong swfpath, since i had moved the js folder to a subfolder. This was only a problem with IE because jplayer has a flash fallback for older browsers that don't do HTML5 very well.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be doing to test this, but Chrome isn't producing an alert from the .html file you linked to

Comment: That code just passed an anonymous function to `getPlaylist`, so you need to figure out why `getPlaylist` isn't calling the provided callback in IE8.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1261672/groovyBox%20-%20Copy/songs.xml is 404'd

Comment: You beat me to it!  @Jack - As a general rule, you should always include an error handler on your ajax calls, not just a success handler.

Comment: Thanks! I see the problem with that now. Still having trouble with the jplayer though...